# Changing background position with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-sprites

Though I can see this question has been asked before I really need a solution without the use of JQuery, its for an embedded web interface and I don't want the overhead of loading jQuery. I need to be able to manipulate sprites using just the JS on the single page, the state of the sprite is dependent on certain JS variables. I'm sure this must be possible, but can't find anything without the use of JQuery.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use different class names and change those classes using JavaScript.

Comment: give us an example of your html http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://javascript.gakaa.com/style-backgroundposition.aspx

Comment: document.getElementById("some_id").setAttribute("style","background-position:center;");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (I think) is to define your own css classes and change those clasess on certan events. i.e.

```
<style type="text/css">
.bg1{
/* Some attributes set here */
background-position:cen‌​ter;
}
.bg2{
/* Some attributes set here */
background-position:left;
}

</style>
```

and then you put your javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("some_id").class = "bg2";
```

Comment: Thanks this was basically the solution I used except I used the function: document.getElementById("some_id").className as .class didn't seem to work?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use Object.style.backgroundPosition="position" to change your desired background position .

Try this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div
{
background-image: url('example.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundPosition="center bottom";  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Position background image</button>
<br>
<div id="div1">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundposition.asp)

Comment: Firefox 26 doesn't react to backgroundPosition changes. When defined in CSS .styyle.backgroundPosition is undefined. It's not documented on MDN.